# Split a String, based on Format? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api

I am writing a simple interface to the FireText SMS service, one of the things I need to do is based on the response, display a message.

So for this example I am checking the number of credits on the Account, the response comes back as a string in the following format

```
 <status no>:<no of credits remaining> <description> - eg: 0:1652 Successful Request
```

Which I can display fine, however, I need to find a way to split out those 3 parts and store them separately so I can use them as required i.e. Check Status No, then if 0 Show Credits, else show Message?

How can I do this, is trying to split the string the best way?

The language used is VB.NET and is using a WebAPI with the Post method.

I am a fairly junior programmer, doing this project for "fun", and so I apologise, if my skills are not 100%.

Thanks

Comment: A string can be splitted using the Split method. [See the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses regular expression like a previous exmample, but I think people are getting confused with the format of the string in your example. This code works based on your example

> 0:1652 Successful Request

The function `ProcessAccountResponse` returns an object you can easily access the values you want.

Make sure to import `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim retObj As AccountResponse = ProcessAccountResponse("0:01652 Successful Request")

    Console.WriteLine("Status Number: " + retObj.StatusNumber.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Number of Credits: " + retObj.CreditsRemaining.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Description: " + retObj.Description)

End Sub


Private Function ProcessAccountResponse(response As string) As AccountResponse

    Const regrPattern As String = "(\d):(\d*) (.*)"

    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(response, regrPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    If(match.Success) Then

        Return New AccountResponse With {.StatusNumber = match.Groups(1).Value, .CreditsRemaining = match.Groups(2).Value, .Description = match.Groups(3).Value}

    Else
        '// Not a valid response
    End If

End Function

Public Class AccountResponse
    Public Property StatusNumber As Integer
    Public Property CreditsRemaining As Integer
    Public Property Description As string
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok - of course you may need to change the data types in the structure and the function according to your needs.

```
Structure Account
    Dim StatusNumber As Integer
    Dim CreditsRemaining As Integer
    Dim Description As String
End Structure


Private Function DecodeResult(resultString As String) As Account
    Dim splitstring() As String = Split(resultString, ">")
    DecodeResult.StatusNumber = CInt(Split(splitstring(0), "<")(1))
    DecodeResult.CreditsRemaining = CInt(Split(splitstring(1), "<")(1))
    DecodeResult.Description = Split(splitstring(2), "<")(1)
End Function


Private Sub btnEvaluate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEvaluate.Click
    Dim x As Account = DecodeResult(result)
    Console.WriteLine(x.StatusNumber)
    Console.WriteLine(x.CreditsRemaining)
    Console.WriteLine(x.Description)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Regular Expression Matches, capture the content between the the < and > signs.
Create a Windows Form (Form1, Textbox1, Listbox1, Button1) and try out the code below:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Clear the box each time the button is clicked
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        ' Input string.
        Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim

        Dim pattern As String = "<(.*?)>"

        For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(match.Groups(1).Value)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-5

Answer (score -1):

I would just split and then use an extension method to get a 'ToDictionary' with Linq extensions.  Here is a simple console application for example.  What you want to get is 'well formed' it seems and do that you probably want something like:

```
Key: Value
```

Which is a dictionary which is a collection that is non repeating of a key of something and a value of it.  In the code below I put in some meaningful data as an example when it is extracted a little different than yours.  You may sometimes have empties but for purpose of example I chose to have data.  Essentially I am

A. making a mockup with s as a variable

B. using extension methods after the s to first get a substring of everything after the first character, to not have the "<" for the split.

C. Splitting on "<" to get the string into a list a strings.

D. Doing a 'ToDictionary' and the 'Function(x)' are just lambda syntax to essentially deal with the variable x like it was the string in the list.  Essentially I am saying 'give me everything left of ">"' for a key and everything to the right for the value.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s = "<status no>123<no of credits remaining>0<description>0:1652 Successful Request"

    Dim split = s.Substring(1, Len(s) - 1).Split("<").ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(">")), Function(x) x.Substring(x.IndexOf(">") + 1, Len(x) - x.IndexOf(">") - 1))

    split.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key} {x.Value}"))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why am I getting a thumbs down?

Comment: I think op wasn't clear in the example. "<status no>:<no of credits remaining> <description>" is the format, where "0:1652 Successful Request" was the response string. Others thought the same as you and because OP couldn't get it work he down voted.